# What does ENDOFTEXT mean in this Perl code?

Tags: perl

I'd like to know what `ENDOFTEXT` means in this Perl script:

```
print <<ENDOFTEXT;
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Hello World!</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<H4>Hello World!</H4>
<P>You have reached <a href="$url">$url</a></P>
<P>Your IP Address is $ip</P>
<H5>Have a nice day!</H5>
</BODY>
</HTML>
ENDOFTEXT
exit(0);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an operator, called a heredoc or here-document. Amusingly enough the reference in perldoc is not as easy to find as it should be. It is useful for being able to quote a large section of text without having to bother with escaping special variables.

You can read the [Here document article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heredoc) on wikipedia as well. The entry you are looking for is `<<EOF` under [Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) from perldoc. I'm citing it here for ease of use:

> A line-oriented form of quoting is
> based on the shell "here-document"
> syntax. Following a << you specify a
> string to terminate the quoted
> material, and all lines following the
> current line down to the terminating
> string are the value of the item. The
> terminating string may be either an
> identifier (a word), or some quoted
> text. An unquoted identifier works
> like double quotes. There may not be a
> space between the << and the
> identifier, unless the identifier is
> explicitly quoted. (If you put a space
> it will be treated as a null
> identifier, which is valid, and
> matches the first empty line.)
>
> The
> terminating string must appear by
> itself (unquoted and with no
> surrounding whitespace) on the
> terminating line.
>
> If the terminating
> string is quoted, the type of quotes
> used determine the treatment of the
> text.

Answer (score 9):

It's a here-document or [heredoc](http://perl.about.com/od/perltutorials/qt/perlheredoc.htm). The ENDOFTEXT is just some arbitrary sequence that marks the end of it; it doesn't mean anything in itself. (I would be more inclined to use END but that's just personal taste.)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to what other people said, I should note that the book [Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735) recommends to avoid using bareword here-docs (e.g: "<<EOF") and instead explicitly quote every here-doc as either <<'EOF' or <<"EOF". This is because people often don't know what is the case for the bareword EOF.

Answer (score 3):

The `ENDOFTEXT` string signifies the beginning and end of a "here-document".  It is described in the official Perl documentation (search for `EOF`): [Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators). It is an arbitrary string; the code could have used the string `FOO` with the same effect.  It allows multi-line quoting, and in this case, variables will be interpolated.